# isVid parameter in Brightcove

Tags: brightcove

Good morning,

does anybody know anything about the purpose of the value:  `<param name="isVid" value="true" />` in the brightcove player-configuration?

on the website they just say that it's a bool-value and has to be set to "true". Nothing about what it's doing.

Comment: I would guess it's a just legacy thing. There's no situation you should omit it or set it to false AFAIK.

Comment: thanks for the information. I tried setting it false and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `isVid` is required when you embbed a video inside an `HTML` file,

```
<script  language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="
http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<object id="myPlayer"  class="BrightcoveExperience">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="width" value="486" />
<param name="height" value="412" />
<param name="playerID" value="1234567890" />
<param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAAstMe5SE~,5vOZ123456789bOfHyhc1i" />
<param name="isVid" value="true" />
<param name="@videoPlayer"  value="ref:myVid12345" />
</object>
```

I think is not well described on the docs...

> **isVid:**    Boolean Required to be true for all video players.
>   http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/player-configuration-parameters